# CheckStyle-like Eclipse-plugin for CSS and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, eclipse, plugins

I'm currently writing on some coding and style guidelines regarding JavaScript and CSS parts of projects. Eclipse offers some basic functionality in this area for situations where code is generated but is there also something en-par with CheckStyle for at least marking guideline-violations as warnings/errors?

Or how do you handle coding guidelines with JS and CSS?

Answer (score 2):

I use [JSLint](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jslint.com%2F&rct=j&q=jslint&ei=z_q2TJbANdaSjAeiovGaCg&usg=AFQjCNFjLfVp6pPd5KEN2N1wNd2rgYJsIA&sig2=i4-IAbjDEAdkiS0SlAMzAQ&cad=rja) for my JavaScript coding guidelines, and it looks as if there's a JSLint plugin for Eclipse [here](http://www.rockstarapps.com/joomla-1.5.8/products/jslint-eclipse-plugin.html)

Comment: Thank you :-) But I need a bit more than "just" semantical validation, e.g. commenting of functions, global comments per file etc.

Answer (score 2):

try this check style module for JavaScript: https://github.com/davepacheco/jsstyle

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you get [**JS Hint**](http://jshint.com/)  for the JavaScript check-style , you can install in your eclipse .